# What's the purpose of PHP7's returning values type declaration

Tags: php, php-7

I'm reading the new features of PHP7 and this doubt comes to me with this one:

[Returning values: Return type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration)

```
function sum($a, $b): float {
    return $a + $b;
}

// Note that a float will be returned.
var_dump(sum(1, 2));
```

The only purpose I can find is to be more specific in interface definition (which is an advantage). But, is there any other reason of including them in every method?

Comment: it also helps you prevent override types from parent class. if your class returns float your overrided method should return float too. which is really useful though

Comment: One of other reason could be IDE type checking. Meaning that IDE helps you if you can pass that variable to function if it accepts only bool.

Comment: @Akintunde isn't it [strict typing](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) made for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing a library for other code to consume, it's good to have a well-defined API, and declared return types are part of that. It saves people having to ferret around in the source code to work it out.

For your own code usage, it's a safety check that you're writing your function correctly, and staying "on plan". It encourages your functions to do one thing, and to stay focused. PHP itself is a bit of a mess in places where it has functions which might return an integer value *or a boolean* if something didn't go according to plan. This is pretty terrible coding. It means the calling code has to code for both eventualities, which it shouldn't need to do. If you specify a return type on your function, you'll not be able to go down that route.

Also as others have said, it helps your IDE to work out what's supposed to be going on as well. That's handy. IDEs will also leverage those phpdoc annotation comments, but they're comments so they lie, and don't actually enforce a contract, so aren't really... a good thing.